# JSF inputText Tag: Translate label attribute

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to translate de label attribute of an inputText but I don't know if it is possible.

My code is the following:

```
<h:outputLabel for="input_titulo" value="#{msg.titulo}"/>
<h:inputText value="#{bean.titulo}" id="input_titulo" 
  required="true" label="#{msg.titulo}">
<f:validateLength maximum="255" />
</h:inputText>
```

The "titulo" is a key of the Messages.properties I am working with and it is showing well in the outputLabel tag.

But when the validation error is shown, the label of the field is empty:

"": La longitud del valor es mayor al máximo permitido de 255 caracteres.

I am working with myfaces 2.0.2 implementation.

Comment: MyFaces 2.0.2 :o That's is nearly a decade old. You might want to upgrade to the latest in order to exclude that your problem is actually by an already long fixed bug.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a workaround to solve this issue without upgrading the version of myfaces?

Comment: One way is, unpack MyFaces JAR, apply exactly same fix as they did, repack it and replace the original one. But this is really kind of crazy.

Comment: Thanks. It is kind of crazy but at least it is a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in myfaces 2.0.2 implementation related to my issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-1729

I tried with myfaces 2.2.12 and it works ok.

Comment: Great it works. Next time please always try things like this before post questions. And why not use 2.3.x instead of 2.2.12?